# navigation drawer тормозит

Tags: java, android, android-navigation-drawer

не знаю как объяснить проблему,пытаюсь коротка объяснить. этот вопрос связан с моим предыдущий вопросом.
[Доступ к getAssets () из другого статического класса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/473594/%D0%94%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF-%D0%BA-getassets-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0)

есть Navigation Drawer и он открыв 3 фрагмента и каждый Фрагмент открывает внутри себя 3 фрагмента через табы. Все работает отлично и ни каких проблем, однако при вызове метод `loadSound` из статического класса больше чем 5 раз, navigation начинает тормозить.

MainActivity:

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mListViewDrawerMenu;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private DrawerMenuItemAdapter mDrawerMenuItemAdapter;


    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mListViewDrawerMenu = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_drawer_menu);


        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);


        if (Locale.getDefault().getLanguage().equals("ar")){
            getWindow().getDecorView().setLayoutDirection(mToolbar.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
            mToolbar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
            mToolbar.setTitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.TextColorToolBar));

        }else {
            getWindow().getDecorView().setLayoutDirection(mToolbar.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_LTR);

            if (Locale.getDefault().getLanguage().equals("en"))
            {
                mToolbar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
                mToolbar.setTitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.TextColorToolBar));
            }else {
                mToolbar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
                mToolbar.setTitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.TextColorToolBar));
            }


        }


        List<DrawerMenuItem> menuItems = generateDrawerMenuItems();
        mDrawerMenuItemAdapter = new DrawerMenuItemAdapter(menuItems,this);
        mListViewDrawerMenu.setAdapter(mDrawerMenuItemAdapter);

        mListViewDrawerMenu.setOnItemClickListener(this);


        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,mDrawerLayout,mToolbar,R.string.app_name,R.string.app_name){
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);



        if(savedInstanceState == null){
            setFragment(0, AnimalsFragment.class);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mListViewDrawerMenu)) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mListViewDrawerMenu);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }


    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        switch (position){
            case 0:
                setFragment(0,AnimalsFragment.class);
                break;
            case 1:
                setFragment(1,BirdsFragment.class);
                break;
            case 2:
               setFragment(2,InsectsFragment.class);
                break;

        }
    }

    public void setFragment(int position,Class<? extends Fragment> fragmentClass){

        try {
            Fragment fragment = fragmentClass.newInstance();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_container,fragment,fragmentClass.getSimpleName());
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

            mListViewDrawerMenu.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mListViewDrawerMenu);
            mListViewDrawerMenu.invalidateViews();


        }catch (Exception ex){
           /* String err = (ex.getMessage()==null)?"Errorrrrr":ex.getMessage();
            Log.e("sdcard-err2:",err);*/
            Log.e("Fragment",ex.getMessage());

        }

    }

    private List<DrawerMenuItem> generateDrawerMenuItems() {
        String[] itemsText = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);
        TypedArray itemsIcon = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);
        List<DrawerMenuItem> result = new ArrayList<DrawerMenuItem>();

        if (Locale.getDefault().getLanguage().equals("ar")){
            for (int i = 0; i < itemsText.length; i++) {
                DrawerMenuItem item = new DrawerMenuItem();
                item.setIcon(itemsIcon.getResourceId(i, -1));
                item.setText(itemsText[i]);
                result.add(item);
            }

        }else {
            for (int i = 0; i < itemsText.length; i++) {
                DrawerMenuItem item = new DrawerMenuItem();
                item.setText(itemsText[i]);
                item.setIcon(itemsIcon.getResourceId(i, -1));
                result.add(item);
            }
        }

        return result;

    }
```

Navigation adapter:

```
public class DrawerMenuItemAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    List<DrawerMenuItem> mItems;
    Context mContext;

    public DrawerMenuItemAdapter(List<DrawerMenuItem> mItems, Context mContext) {
        this.mItems = mItems;
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mItems.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        public ImageView imageIcon;
        public TextView tvTitle;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView==null){
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_drawer_menu_item,null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.imageIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_drawer_menu_item_icon);
            holder.tvTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_drawer_menu_item_text);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else {
            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }

        DrawerMenuItem item = mItems.get(position);
        holder.tvTitle.setText(item.getText());
        holder.imageIcon.setImageResource(item.getIcon());


        return convertView;
    }
}
```

фрагмент который вызывает 3 фрагмента:

```
public class AnimalsPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

   private Activity mActivity;

    public AnimalsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Activity mActivity) {
        super(fm);
        this.mActivity = mActivity;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position){
            case 0:
                HerbivoreFragment herbivoreFragment = new HerbivoreFragment();
                return herbivoreFragment;
            case 1:
            CarnivoreFragment carnivoreFragment = new CarnivoreFragment();
             //   return carnivoreFragment.getClass().getSimpleName();
                return carnivoreFragment;

            case 2:
                SeaAnimalsFragment seaAnimalsFragment = new SeaAnimalsFragment();
                return seaAnimalsFragment;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                return mActivity.getString(R.string.herbivore) ;
            case 1:
                return mActivity.getString(R.string.carnivore) ;
            case 2:
                return mActivity.getString(R.string.seaAnimals) ;
        }

        return null;

    }
}
```

Проблема тут, когда я пытаюсь вызвать  метод `loadSound` из статического класса больше чем 5 раз, navigation начинает тормозить, когда хочу его использовать.

```
public class CarnivoreFragment extends Fragment {

    private int mAlligatorSound,mBatSound,mBearSound,mBobcatSound,mCatSound,mCheetahSound,mCoyoteSound,
    mCrocodileSound,mDogSound,mFoxSound,mHyenaSound,mJaguarSound,mKittenSound,mLeopardSound,
    mLionSound,mPuppySound,mRattleSnakeSound,mSnakeSound,mTigerSound,mWolfSound;

    private View view;

    public CarnivoreFragment() {
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_carnivore, container, false);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {

            Sound.createOldSoundPool();
        } else {
            Sound.createNewSoundPool();
        }

        mAlligatorSound = Sound.loadSound(getContext(),"alligator.wav");
        mBatSound = Sound.loadSound(getContext(), "bat.mp3");
        mBearSound = Sound.loadSound(getContext(),"bear.wav");
        mBobcatSound=Sound.loadSound(getContext(),"bobcat.mp3");
        mCatSound=  Sound.loadSound(getContext(),"cat.wav");
        mCheetahSound=  Sound.loadSound(getContext(),"cheetah.wav");
        mCoyoteSound=  Sound.loadSound(getContext(),"coyote.wav");
        mCrocodileSound=  Sound.loadSound(getContext(),"crocodile.wav");
        mDogSound=  Sound.loadSound(getContext(),"dog.wav");
        mFoxSound=  Sound.loadSound(getContext(),"fox.mp3");
        mHyenaSound=  Sound.loadSound(getContext(),"hyena.wav");
        mJaguarSound=  Sound.loadSound(getContext(),"jaguar.wav");
        mKittenSound=  Sound.loadSound(getContext(),"kitten.wav");
        mLeopardSound=  Sound.loadSound(getContext(),"leopard.wav");
        mLionSound=  Sound.loadSound(getActivity(),"lion.wav");
        mPuppySound=  Sound.loadSound(getActivity(),"puppy.wav");
        mRattleSnakeSound=  Sound.loadSound(getActivity(),"rattlesnake.mp3");
        mSnakeSound=  Sound.loadSound(getActivity(),"snake.wav");
        mTigerSound=  Sound.loadSound(getActivity(),"tiger.wav");
        mWolfSound=  Sound.loadSound(getActivity(),"wolf.wav");

        int idList[]={R.id.imageButtonAlligator,R.id.imageButtonBat,R.id.imageButtonBear,R.id.imageButtonBobCat,R.id.imageButtonCat,
                      R.id.imageButtonCheetah,R.id.imageButtonCoyote,R.id.imageButtonCrocodile,R.id.imageButtonDog,R.id.imageButtonFox,
                      R.id.imageButtonHyena,R.id.imageButtonJaguar,R.id.imageButtonKitten,R.id.imageButtonLeopard,R.id.imageButtonLion,
                      R.id.imageButtonPuppy,R.id.imageButtonRattlesnake,R.id.imageButtonSnake,R.id.imageButtonTiger,R.id.imageButtonWolf};

        for (int id :idList){
            ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(id);
            imageButton.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        }



        return view;
    }

    View.OnClickListener onClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.imageButtonAlligator:
                    Sound.playSound(mAlligatorSound);
                    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),R.string.Alligator, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case R.id.imageButtonBat:
                    Sound.playSound(mBatSound);
                    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),R.string.Bat, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case R.id.imageButtonBear:
                    Sound.playSound(mBearSound);
                    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),R.string.Bear, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case R.id.imageButtonBobCat:
                    Sound.playSound(mBobcatSound);
                    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),R.string.BobCat, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case R.id.imageButtonCat:
                    Sound.playSound(mCatSound);
                    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),R.string.Cat, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case R.id.imageButtonCheetah:
                    Sound.playSound(mCheetahSound);
                    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),R.string.Cheetah, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case R.id.imageButtonCoyote:
                    Sound.playSound(mCoyoteSound);
                    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),R.string.Coyote, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case R.id.imageButtonCrocodile:
                    Sound.playSound(mCrocodileSound);
                    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),R.string.Crocodile, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case R.id.imageButtonDog:
                    Sound.playSound(mDogSound);
                    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),R.string.Dog, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case R.id.imageButtonFox:
                    Sound.playSound(mFoxSound);
                    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),R.string.Fox, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case R.id.imageButtonHyena:
                    Sound.playSound(mHyenaSound);
                    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),R.string.Hyena, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case R.id.imageButtonJaguar:
                    Sound.playSound(mJaguarSound);
                    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),R.string.Jaguar, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case R.id.imageButtonKitten:
                    Sound.playSound(mKittenSound);
                    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),R.string.Kitten, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case R.id.imageButtonLeopard:
                    Sound.playSound(mLeopardSound);
                    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),R.string.Leopard, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case R.id.imageButtonLion:
                    Sound.playSound(mLionSound);
                    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),R.string.Lion, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case R.id.imageButtonPuppy:
                    Sound.playSound(mPuppySound);
                    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),R.string.Puppy, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case R.id.imageButtonRattlesnake:
                    Sound.playSound(mRattleSnakeSound);
                    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),R.string.RattleSnake, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case R.id.imageButtonSnake:
                    Sound.playSound(mSnakeSound);
                    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),R.string.Snake, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case R.id.imageButtonTiger:
                    Sound.playSound(mTigerSound);
                    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),R.string.Tiger, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case R.id.imageButtonWolf:
                    Sound.playSound(mWolfSound);
                    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),R.string.Wolf, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;

            }

        }
    };
```

Comment: Если начинает тормозить через несколько запусков, то почти стопроцентно проблема в утечке памяти, что при использовании статических классов не удивительно. Поскольку поиск утечек связан с использованием соответствующих инструментов в процессе работы приложения, то работу эту вам придется выполнить самостоятельно. В Android Studio 2 были существенно доработаны инструменты поиска утечек памяти.

Comment: Смотрите [этот вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/465911/177345)